# How to make webpage not responding for testing

Tags: javascript, html, process, electron

I want to make a webpage in not responding state manually. The purpose is to embed webpage inside a webview component in an electron application. so that the renderer process can know the embedded process is not responding, I wish to use the unresponsive event for the webcontents object. Can anyone help?

Comment: have you tried creating an infinite loop ? `while(true){}`

Comment: nop, will it work/

Comment: it should work, that the only way I know to make a web page not responding, electron should react the same way as most browser (since it's built on top of chromium)

Comment: please note that technically the `Not responding` is not a state nor an event of webpage. It is a message from browser.

Answer (score 1):

The [Electron API Demos](https://github.com/electron/electron-api-demos) application has a demo section called **Handling Window Crashes and Hangs** making use of the Electron methods [process.crash()](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/process#processcrash) and [process.hang()](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/process#processhang), which have been specifically designed for this kind of test purposes.

You may try using `process.hang()` somewhere in the relevant renderer process code to simulate an unresponsive webpage...

Answer (score 0):

To make a webpage unresponsive you need an infinite rendering proccess. For example putting infinite images in a webpage:

```js
while (true){
 var elem=document.getElementById("test");
 var img='<img src="test">'
 var data=elem.innerHTML;
 elem.innerHTML=data + img;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Please note that technically the `Not responding` is not a state nor an event of webpage. It is a message from browser. Infinite rendering loops ends in `Webpage unresponsive` normally. However non-rendering script such as `while(true){}` also ends in errors but perhaps with different messages from browser.